# How can I merge the response from an external service call with the original message in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

From a logical perspective this is the kind of routing behaviour I wish to implement:

[image: Logical view of routing info]

I want to be able to merge the response of an external service with the original request.

I have been able to implement this using multicasting, an aggregator, and a mock endpoint but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way. My current implementation looks like this:

```
        <multicast strategyRef="serviceAggregator" stopOnException="false">
            <to uri="mock:foo" />
            <to uri="http://0.0.0.0:9999/service/?throwExceptionOnFailure=false" />
        </multicast>
        <camel:to uri="log:uk.co.company.aggregated?showAll=true" />
        <to uri="http://0.0.0.0:9999/anotherService/
```

The part I particularly don't like is using a mock endpoint but I also don't think that this is a very readable way to express the above diagram. So I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I didn't include the from and split is the wrong word in EIP terms. I guess I meant split the execution flow and then aggregate the responses - but like Mr Ibsen says it is just simple content enrichment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to read about the EIP patterns, for example the content enricher
http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Where you can merge the reply message with the request message.

Mind the Content Enricher has 2 modes
- enrich
- pollEnrich

Make sure to notice the difference, from the docs in the link above.

```
<route>
  <from uri="...">
  <enrich uri="http://0.0.0.0:9999/service/?throwExceptionOnFailure=false" strategyRef="serviceAggregator"/>
  <to uri="log:uk.co.company.aggregated?showAll=true" />
  <to uri="http://0.0.0.0:9999/anotherService/>
  ...
</route>
```

And yes you diagram is showing splitter,  but the sample code is using multicast EIP.

Comment: Sorry - the diagram was supposed to show the logical part. There is no splitter.

Comment: That's great - thanks!  My wording was just wrong in EIP terms. I do have the EIP book but I've only just begun it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store the original message in a header or property and later do some merge in a bean. Using the header and the current body.

.setHeader("orig", body())
.to("externalService")
.bean(new MyMergeBean())

Comment: Its not a good idea to store in a header, as headers are part of the message format. Storing as a property on the Exchange is the correct place. Using the EIPs is still the best choice IMHO as they express better the intent of the routing flow.